# VB.Net Print Form to PDF Printer

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing

I am trying (and failing) right now to print a Windows Form as a PDF File in VB.Net

Now I know from doing some research that VB.Net does not have any built in function which could allow me to do this without using a third party application.

My way to get around this, was to attempt to print my Form using a PDF Printer, since logically that should work no?  My issue is getting that to work properly.

This is currently my code for attempting to print:

```
Private Sub SelectPrinterThenPrint()
    Dim PrintersDialog As New PrintDialog()
    If PrintersDialog.SHowDialog(Me) = System.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            p_Document = New PrintDocument()
            PrintersDialog.Document = p_Document
            AddHandler p_Document.PrintPage, AddressOf HandleOnPrintPage
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleOnPrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles p_Document.PrintPage
    Dim MorePagesPending = False
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pnlContainer.Width, pnlContainer.Height)
    pnlContainer.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pnlContainer.ClientRectangle)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, New Point(0,0))
    If MorePagesPending Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    Else
        e.HasMorePages = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The `SelectPrinterThenPrint()` method is called when a button on my Form is clicked.  Right now I am having two issues.

1) I don't know how to setup where the file gets saved.  The Print Dialog opens, and I get to select my PDF Printer, but it doesn't let me set a filename.  So how do I set the filename I want to be printing to?

2) Because I can't tell if the file is actually being saved, I can't tell if I am actually setting up the print properly or not.  I am trying to print the entire contents of a panel, which holds all the elements I want on my PDF file.  One thing I am unsure about however, is that the form the panel is displayed in, is not the same size as the panel.  The Form the panel is in has the same width, but not the same height, with the form being set up for auto scrolling.  Will I get the whole Panel to print?  Or just the part the is visible in the form at the time of printing?

Comment: You forgot *p_Document.Print()* after the line: *AddHandler p_Document.PrintPage, AddressOf HandleOnPrintPage*. Also set *PrintDialog.AllowPrintToFile = True*. I believe it is the default setting but do it anyway.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Thanks, I just realized this myself.  God I feel dumb sometimes.